# List C# find element by id in list with class items

Tags: c#, list

I have made class in c#. after I had been a list consists from this class. the class has attribute groupId (The elements do not follow each other). I want to get the elements by the groupId.
this is the class:

```
class GroupListItem
{
    public GroupListItem(List<string> placeIdString)
    {
        GroupId = id++;
        PlaceIdString = placeIdString;
    }
    private static int id=0;
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public List<String> PlaceIdString { get; set; }
}
```

this is the list declaration:

```
List<GroupListItem> groupListItems = new List<GroupListItem>();
```

Comment: `I want to get the elements by the groupId` ← Do you mean you want to filter the existing `List<GroupListItem>` instance by an ID? There are many examples of how to do this on [so] and other sites. You can use loops (pick one and try it) or Linq / Lambdas which abstracts the loops for you.

Comment: var resuts = groupListItems.Where(x => x.id == 1234).Select(x => x.PlaceIdString).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
int myValue....
.... groupListItems.Where(i => i.GroupId == myValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

the where doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0